# Gitorious.org: all projects not showing

Tags: git, gitorious

I am a new user on gitorious.org

I can't access all the projects on https://gitorious.org/projects . The website shows 693 pages of projects but every page beyond the 33rd is BLANK. IS there any reason why ?

Also can someone show me where all the projects on the website would be located ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You should probably email the people at Gitorious to ask them what's going on.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a but on a third-party website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that page 33 and beyond are blank.  Seems like gitorious has a bug.  You should report it.  As for where the projects actually live... if you click on one (on a page that isn't blank) You get to the project page for that project, e.g., when I click on Qt on page 1 I go to https://qt.gitorious.org/qt  on the right hand side of that page there is a list of repositories.  I assume that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the information, much appreciated.
I was looking for small open source projects to read on. 
Wikipedia says that gitorious.org has over 30,000 projects so I was wondering where the rest went.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, consider selecting it as the answer :-)